# Automatical padding between divs - NO bootstrap

Tags: html, css

So I have a question about css. Is it possible to get this design without using padding on the "5 divs element"?

I cannot hardcode values in the style-tag in each div because it's going to be used in a foreach loop (but the width is going to be the same - 5 divs in each row)
I don't want to use pseudo((::after a certain div)) because I don't know how many divs there going to be in total.

If I'm using: `width: calc(100% / 5 - *number of padding* px)`

and then using `padding: *number of padding* px;`

on the 5 divs my outer divs is not on the right place (not on the line like they are supposed to be).

Any idea how I can get this in the best way [NO bootstrap]?

[image: padding]

Comment: You can use `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`

Comment: the container is `overflow: auto`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use flexbox. Use `justify-content: space-between` to get the result you want.

You can increase the padding between the divs by decreasing the width.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  width: 19%;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox in CSS3 (Guide here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first remove the padding from `100%` then divide by `5`. In your case, you will have 4 padding between your element so the formula should be:

```
 calc((100% - 4*padding)/5);
```

Example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border:1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  width: calc((100% - 4*10px)/5);
  background: red;
  margin:10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```